# darwin demo not working on Indigo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

darwin demo not working on Indigo: any thoughts? Will continue to investigate.

```
rosrun darwin_gazebo walker_demo.py
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425405793.824262] [0.000000] Instantiating Darwin Client
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425405793.828103] [0.000000] Waiting for joints to be populated...
```

Darwin does not walk. The following is the terminal window of the

```
roslaunch darwin_gazebo darwin_gazebo.launch


process[darwin/controller_spawner-5]: started with pid [26073]
process[robot_state_publisher-6]: started with pid [26076]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher
process[darwin_walker-7]: started with pid [26106]
Msg Waiting for master.[ INFO] [1425406138.208082461]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
Msg Waiting for master[ INFO] [1425406138.209592296]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.10.142
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406138.630773] [0.000000] Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.10.142
[ INFO] [1425406140.919091541]: Camera Plugin (robotNamespace = /), Info: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1425406141.030590613]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[spawn_urdf-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/richard/.ros/log/5be7f30a-c1d0-11e4-86bd-801934b8af01/spawn_urdf-4*.log
[ INFO] [1425406143.478498396]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ INFO] [1425406143.478872041]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /darwin
[ INFO] [1425406143.480651047]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [/robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[ INFO] [1425406143.787210501]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.070854] [0.000000] Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.072983] [0.000000] Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.075159] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_pan_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.226311] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_tilt_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.281557] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_gripper_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.336907] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_gripper_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.391317] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_pelvis_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.446336] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_thigh1_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.500809] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_thigh2_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.562269] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_tibia_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.621899] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_ankle1_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.675579] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_ankle2_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.727414] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_pelvis_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.782862] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_thigh1_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.841203] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_thigh2_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.900158] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_tibia_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406144.958777] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_ankle1_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.015054] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_ankle2_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.069730] [0.000000] Loading controller: joint_state_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.164760] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_shoulder_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.219832] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_high_arm_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.280902] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_low_arm_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.335662] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_wrist_l_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.388600] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_shoulder_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.443592] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_high_arm_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.497760] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_low_arm_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.562284] [0.000000] Loading controller: j_wrist_r_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1425406145.618783] [0.000000] Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: j_pan_position_controller, j_tilt_position_controller, j_gripper_l_position_controller, j_gripper_r_position_controller, j_pelvis_l_position_controller, j_thigh1_l_position_controller, j_thigh2_l_position_controller, j_tibia_l_position_controller, j_ankle1_l_position_controller, j_ankle2_l_position_controller, j_pelvis_r_position_controller, j_thigh1_r_position_controller, j_thigh2_r_position_controller, j_tibia_r_position_controller, j_ankle1_r_position_controller, j_ankle2_r_position_controller, joint_state_controller, j_shoulder_l_position_controller, j_high_arm_l_position_controller, j_low_arm_l_position_controller, j_wrist_l_position_controller, j_shoulder_r_position_controller, j_high_arm_r_position_controller, j_low_arm_r_position_controller, j_wrist_r_position_controller
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8152/darwin-demo-not-working-on-indigo/) by [richardnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/882/richardnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2015-03-04**:
Probably upstream authors of darwin gazebo simulation can help your more. https://github.com/HumaRobotics/darwin_gazebo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I resubmitted this to the upstream authors as per comment.

---

Originally posted by [richardnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/882/richardnunziata/) with karma: 1 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0